# Rails and forms: drop down with range of numbers and Unlimited

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu

I have this right now:

```
<%= f.select :credit, (0..500) %>
```

This will result in this:

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
...
```

How would I add another option in that select that would be "**All**" and which value should be **nil**?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will *almost* do what you want:

```
<%= f.select :credit, ((0..500).map {|i| [i,i] } << ["No limit",nil]) %>
```

`select` can take a number of formats for the list of options.  One of them is an array of arrays, as given here.  Each element in the outer array is a 2-element array, containing the displayed option text and the form value, in that order.

The `map` above turns `(0..500)` into an array like this, where the option displayed is identical to the form value.  Then one last option is added.

Note that this will produce a value of "" (an empty string) for the parameter if "Unlimited" is selected - if you put a select field into a form and the form is submitted, the browser will send *something* for that form parameter, and there is no way to send `nil` as a form parameter explicitly.  If you *really* wanted to you could use some clever javascript to get the browser to not send the parmeter at all, but that would be more work than simply adding:

```
param[:credit] == "" and param[:credit] = nil
```

to your controller action.

Answer (score 9):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use `options_for_select` and `prompt` to do this a little more cleanly than what is shown in the selected answer:

```
<%= f.select :credit, options_for_select(0..500), { prompt: "No Limit" } %>
```

See the docs here:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select