# how can we have double digit range drop downs in rails forms? that gerates drop down with numbers like 00,01, 02 etc, instead 0,1 , 2 etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, double, range, digit

How Can we have a double digit drop downs for minutes and hours selection, in rails forms? i checked the range drop downs in rails, but it is generating single digit numbers in drop down like 0, 1, 2 etc,but  i wanted to generate these numbers like 00, 01,02 etc.,

Comment: Which form helper method are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038993/rails-and-forms-drop-down-with-range-of-numbers-and-unlimited, this link iam following. can we generate the double digit numbers similarly? by passing any extra attributes for these range dropdowns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add something like this:

```
"%02d" % number
```

It will return for example

```
"%02d" % 1
=> "01"

"%02d" % 51
=> "51"
```

For your example it could be:

```
<%= f.select :credit, (0..500).map { |i| "%03d" % i }  %>
```

Comment: iam following this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038993/rails-and-forms-drop-down-with-range-of-numbers-and-unlimited, where can i write the above logic in this case?

Comment: I edited my answer to show what it could look like for your specified example. You should also consider updating your question to reflect the actual code you were using.